# Mouse over link action in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to have a link in a SSRS report appear differently when you mouse over it?  For example, in many websites (like stackoverflow), the link is in blue, but not underlined, until you mouse over it.

I've seen this link as a possibility of using style sheets:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345247.aspx

"Modifying style sheets has no effect on the appearance of published reports that you run on a report server. In Reporting Services, reports do not reference style sheets. Ad hoc reports that are auto-generated by the report server use style information that is stored as an embedded resource in the report server program files. Reports that you create in Report Designer use the fonts, colors, and layout that you specify in the report definition. Styles are created inline with the rest of the layout."

I don't understand the last sentence though "inline with the rest of the layout"   I take it that they aren't referring to link formatting.  In any case, I tried changing it without success.

I'm using SQL Server 2012

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this will work, but check out the Reporting Services\ReportManager\Styles folder on the server.

You'll see a ReportingSerivces.css file, try editing that...

If that's not the right file, you can poke around in the others or use a code inspector (developer tools/mode) in your browser to see what css is being used.

Then you'd need to find what class your link is using and restyle it.

```
.DrillDown:hover
{
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: Verdana;
    color: #FF3300;
    text-decoration: underline
}
```

Comment: How do I find out what class my link is using?

Comment: Use Firebug in Firefox or developer tools in IE/Chrome.  You'll be able to activate a mode (by pressing a magnifying glass usually) which will let you mouse over the elements on your page and see related window in a pane.  Or you could view the source of the web page and try to find the class/id of your element there.

Comment: I've changed the .css files but it's not really changing anything.  Will have to try again next week.  Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

At least in SSRS2019 as this only where I have tried. You can actually select the text in your textbox and right click to edit the Placeholder Properties...
In there you can set markup type as html then surround your text with a span tag then include onmouseover and onmouseout events. For example for a hyperlink to add an underline:

```
<span onmouseover="this.style.textDecorationLine='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecorationLine='none'">...</span>
```

Having saying that I have managed to get some things working but not others so there are limitations e.g. this.style.textDecorationColor to change the color of the underline did nothing.